# Where do the movies fit within there series timeline?

Tags: nanoha

I have all three seasons of Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha and the two movies. I am wondering where the movies occur chronologically within in the series. So I can watch them in the proper order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two Nanoha movies are retellings of the first and second seasons of the anime respectively. That is to say that "Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha: The Movie 1st" covers the same story as the original "Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha" and "Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha: The Movie 2nd A's" covers the same part of the story as "Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha A's". The not-yet-aired third movie is supposedly going to be an original story which will be set between A's and StrikerS on the timeline.

There are some minor differences between the anime and the movies. Technically, the movies form their own continuity. However, these differences are all minor as far as I remember. With that in mind, there are many possible orders to watch the series, and so long as you respect the internal chronology any viewing order seems reasonable. If you want to watch all the anime in chronological order by release date (which is what I'd personally recommend), it would be:

1. Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha
2. Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha A's
3. Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS
4. Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha: The Movie 1st
5. Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha: The Movie 2nd A's

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent response provided by Logan M, these are the anime and manga series in a chronological order. The *Vivid* and *Force* manga series continue the story from the anime, while the other manga entries are nothing more than additional background content for the die-hard fan

- **Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha** or **Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha: The Movie 1st**
- *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha MOVIE 1st THE COMICS (Manga)*
- **Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha A's** or **Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha: The Movie 2nd**
- *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha A's (Manga)*
- **Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS**
- *Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS THE COMICS (Manga)*
- *Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha ViVid (Manga)*
- *Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha Force (Manga)*

Please do note that the movies are alternate retellings that are not 100% story-wise compatible with the original series. In **StrikerS** there are a number of background references to story from A's which has been scrapped in the movie retelling. I would recommend going through the original series (Nanoha, A's and StrikerS) prior to watching the movie retelling and/or reading the manga.